# Improve search for files by pathnames with locate and grep pipeline

Tags: grep, search, locate

I often use the following pipeline of `locate` (from `findutils`) and `grep` to find files whose pathnames contain two words `word1` and `word2`, without any specific order between each other:

```
locate -i word1 | grep -i  word2
```

I was wondering how to do that with a single non-pipeline command alone? Is it a better way than my pipeline command?

Does `locate` support some regex in which we can formulate my search pattern?

Thanks.

Solution with `find` is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448006/674

Comment: `locate`
 assumes a background process scanning your disk via cron somewhere during the day. I prefer disabling it on servers and living with `find`. When you have hundred of servers you want to remove that kind of simultaneous "random" activity.

Comment: @Rui: `find` is too much slower than `locate`.

Comment: Obviously. On the other hand, it just happens where and when you want it.

Comment: Are you sure that the updating of the database of `locate` is scheduled by `cron`, where can I find it out?

Comment: I deleted it on my servers... `/etc/cron.daily` or `/etc/cron.weekly`
, cannot remember which.

Comment: there are several versions of `locate` (including GNU locate, part of findutils; slocate; mlocate - probably the most commonly used these days) - which one are you asking about?

Comment: @Tim, search for "updatedb" and "mlocate" in your system crons.

Comment: @Rui: Are the two files created by your OS?

Comment: @Tim Those two directories are standard to Linux. I did not delete them, just the `updatedb`
 invocation.

Comment: @Rui: wonder why you don't want the cron tasks? Why "When you have hundred of servers you want to remove that kind of simultaneous "random" activity"?

Comment: the I/O adds up, and most of it is remote. NFS or iSCSI servers on the other end. Having a couple of hundred servers hammering your NAS at the same time *is not good*.

Comment: some versions of `locate` support regex searches....but, like `grep`, they don't support AND or AND NOT logical operations (probably because alternation aka OR is easy, but AND would require either a new regex style or a wrapper language around regexes).  so, piping into another tool like `grep` or `grep -v` is the standard solution.

Comment: `awk` is a good example of such a wrapper language.  e.g. it's easy in awk to do something like `/a|b|c/ && /d|e/ && ! /f|g/`.  There is similar capability in `sed`.  and `perl` (albeit a little more verbosely).   There's little point in that being implemented in `grep` itself when a) it's arguably beyond the scope of a simple tool like `grep`, and b) `awk` etc can already do it.

Comment: `locate ... | grep ` is fine! You may also try locate -r... Example: `locate -r '[Vv]er\we.*\.pdf$'`

Comment: @Tim By default the database is created by a cron script (/etc/cron.d/find) and includes files accessable by nobody (see https://wiki.debian.org/locate). Could be diffentent on other distros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That very much depends on your implementation of `locate`.** That's not a standard command and there are a few different implementations with quite significant differences.

1. **There's one implementation in GNU findutils.**

   With that one:

   ```
   locate -i word1 word2
   ```

   locates files whose path contains either `word1` or `word2` case
   insensitively while

   ```
   locate -Ai word1 word2
   ```

   locates files whose path contains both.

   It also supports a `--regex` and `--regextype` option like for GNU 
   `find`. By defaut, that's `emacs`-style regexps, some form of hybrid
   between BRE and ERE.

   With that one, you could do:

   ```
   locate -ir 'word1.*word2\|word2.*word1'
   ```
2. **The `mlocate` implementation (the default on Debian and derivatives)** also support `-A`. It has `-r`/`--regex`, but not
   `--regextype` and its REs are Basic Regular Expressions. On systems
   like GNU ones whose BREs support `\|` for alternation as an
   extension, you can also do:

   ```
   locate -ir 'word1.*word2\|word2.*word1'
   ```
3. **ast-open has a `locate` as well as a ksh93 wrapper script around `tw` (the once to be successor of `find`)**. It doesn't support `-A`
   nor `-r`, but you can use the full power of `ksh93` wildcards, so
   you can use for instance perl-like look-ahead operators  with:

   ```
   locate '~(Pi:^(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2))'
   ```

   Or `ksh93`'s `&` glob operator:

   ```
   locate -i '*word1*&*word2*'
   ```

   It's particularly slow compared to the  other ones though as the
   pattern is not anchored. It's better once anchoring (`l`eft and
   `r`ight) is restored with:

   ```
   locate -i '~(lr)*word1*&*word2*'
   ```

---

**One problem with piping to `grep`** is that it doesn't work for file path that contain newline characters. With GNU locate or mlocate, you can use the `-0` option though to use NUL-delimited records which you can use in combination with the `-z` option of GNU `grep`:

```
locate -i0 word1 | grep -z word2 | grep -z word3 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Or `-v RS='\0'` in GNU gawk or @ThomasDickey's `mawk`:

```
locate -i0 word1 | awk -v RS='\0' '/word2/ && /word3/'
```

Or `perl -ln0`:

```
locate -i0 word1 | perl -ln0e 'print if /word2/ && /word3/'
```