# Search for files whose pathnames contain several words without specific order between them

Tags: find, regular-expression

I'd like to search for all files whose pathnames contain several words (`word1`, `word2`), without any particular order between them. 
Examples of matching files are:

```
word1bar/fooword2/myfile
fooword2/word1bar/myfile
fooword2/bar/word1myfile
```

What command may solve the task?

I am guessing some command like this will work:

```
find . -regex regexpattern
```

Thanks.

My solution with `locate` is [Improve search for files by pathnames with locate and grep pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418846/improve-search-for-files-by-pathnames-with-locate-and-grep-pipeline)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard to do with a single pattern (regex or shell), but since `find` can take multiple conditions, we can use

```
find . -type f -path "*word1*" -path "*word2*" ...
```

In regex you'd need to specify all the different permutations of the words, like `.*word1.*word2.*|.*word2.*word1.*` (ERE or Perl RE only), and that blows up quickly if you have more than two words you want to find.